# Incorrect reorder for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder my ggplot, and there are plenty of tutorials on this. All they essentially say is to do the following:

```
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(someValue, -someOtherValue), y = someOtherValue))
```

I've tried to do this for  my geom_col plot and while it definitely looks better it is still not correctly ordered from high to low.

[image]

My code for it is:

```
ggplot(mydata) +geom_col(aes(x= reorder(Product, -Total), y=Total))
```

How would I get the correct ordering from high to low?

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, could you please update your question with some sample data so we can run your code and generate your output on our ends? Thanks!

Comment: Are there errors or warnings? Is `Product` a factor? Is `Total` numeric? Perhaps you want to reorder by the `sum`, rather than the (default) `mean`? I'd guess `aes(x= reorder(Product, -Total, FUN = sum)` will work... you probably have stacked bars with varying numbers of rows per `Product`, so `mean` isn't appropriate.

Comment: Thanks gregor! `FUN = sum` did it!

Comment: Glad it helped. Next time, to get help much faster, please (a) post data from the start, and (b) post actual data as text, not a picture of your data. It was only good luck that I could diagnose your problem without have a bit of usable sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `reorder` uses the mean, that is `reorder(Product, -Total)` takes the mean of the `-Total` for each `Product`. `geom_col` has the default `position = "stack"`, so you are plotting the sum of the `Total` column. Since your data has different numbers of rows for each product, the order of the sum is  different than the order of the mean. So, you need to tell `reorder` to use `sum`, not `mean`. Change to:

```
aes(x= reorder(Product, -Total, FUN = sum))
```